# Change ID attribute of input element not working in jQuery when use PartialView in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I call a view using ajax with the following code:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "html",
   async: true,
   url: "UrlHereController",
   success: function(html){
     $(".element").append(html); // the element is appended in the page

     $("input[name='Name']").attr("id", "myCustomID"); // this is not working
   }
});
```

The above code works perfectly.

my controller looks like:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public PartialViewResult GetEmptyArticleTypeView()
  {
     MyModel model = GenerateEmptyModel();

     return PartialView( "~/pathTo/View.cshtml", model );
  }
```

and inside my view is something relative simple (`View.cshtml`):

```
@model MyModel 

@Html.TextBoxFor( item => item.Name )
@Html.TextBoxFor( item => item.Description)
@Html.TextBoxFor( item => item.Value)
```

on `success` callback function, when I try to change an `id` of an input, it not working.
Still that id has unmodified value.

Why ?

Comment: Have u tried `$(document).find("input[name='Name']").attr("id", "myCustomID");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the timeout between calls to `append` and `$().attr` is very small, so problem might be in the fact that element is not actually added to the DOM by the time `$("input[name='Name']")` is executed. So you can either call `setTimeout` here, or, maybe a bit cleaner, modify the `html` itself before inserting it to the page:

```
var $html = $(html);
$html.find("input[name='Name']").attr("id", "myCustomID");
$(".element").append($html);
```

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. I appended the html and after that change id ... If I do in your way, works.